# Multi Value select refiner customization

Tags: 2013, multi-select

I am using multi select refiners in SharePoint 2013 search page which has "Apply/Clear All" options for each refiner.

I need to provide a single "Apply/Clear All" option for all the available multi value select refiners in the search page.

Any pointers for customizing the display templates or custom visual web part would be helpful